# MEAN: What is the best way to keep a watch on a json file

Tags: node.js, angularjs, matlab, mean-stack

**Some Info:**

I am creating a json file from matlab which updates every second with the latest coordinates.For writing file from matlab to json I am using JsonLab.

**My problem :**

The json file refreshes every second and gets updated .Now i want to show the latest data everytime on the webpage.So this requires loading the json everytime it is refreshed.I am confused about how to do this . I am using MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, Node).
Any help would be appreceiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't consume it with REST then. Implement http://socket.io/ and consume coordinates with web sockets live data.

You can also maybe consider using Firebase ([AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/index.html)) if you want to have your sockets implementation to be someone else's problem.